# Is it bad practice to have a db table containing data calculated from other tables?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am developing a quiz site.  My db schema is such that when a user completes a quiz, all of their answers are stored in a table called responses.  I can go back and calculate the score for a quiz on the fly by a db query.  However, I was wondering if it would be more efficient to store the score for each quiz attempt in a new table for faster lookup since I will have to do some post-processing of my query of the responses table (ie looping over each quiz and then looping over the questions within each quiz to get the score).

Is it bad practice to store data that could, ultimately, be obtained from a query?

Here is a picture of the relevant part of my schema:

[image: Schema]

Thanks

Martyn

Comment: _..I can go back and calculate the score for a quiz on the fly by a db query.._ Exactly! Do that!

Comment: Wow that was a quick response, so does the additional post processing needed to get the information not matter (ie a much smaller cost than more db tables).?

Comment: It could matter but we would talk about some milliseconds - it also depends on your code design how/when and how often you calculate those values

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reassurance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL currently supports views for such calculations but the views aren't "materialized views" so the queries get run every time the view is accessed. While MySQL will do some internal optimization it won't cache the results.

Here is a related post about creating materialized views.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/best-way-to-create-a-materialized-view-in-mysql

To use this capability you'll need to run native queries. MOST other database types support materialized views directly so you'll simply need to check the documentation on how to create a materialized view for your backend database.